# How to connect RabbitMQ's MQTT-Broker ( in java) with a C client running on Bosch XDK IOT device

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, bosch-iot

I am a student and stuck on a project, I need to send data from BOSCH XDK device to my laptop over MQTT. The device would be connected with USB to my laptop and I wish to send data from BOSCH XDK running as MQTT client (running C code using a library provided by Bosch), this data would then be received by RabbitMQ broker ( running Java with RabbitMQ library) on my laptop.

Is this possible at all? i.e. MQTT communication with a client having a different library and implementation language than the MQTT broker/server.

Comment: Libraries can be written in what ever you want, as long as they implement the MQTT protocol properly they will happily interact with any MQTT broker.

Comment: Thanks. And I assume sending data over USB is not a limitation as well? I am asking this because the XDK device always talks about a Wi-Fi connection to the broker!.

Comment: These questions show a fundamental misunderstanding of what MQTT is. I suggest you go read the MQTT spec.

Comment: Sure, I will follow this. Thankyou